# C# MethodInfo to Callable Func - Expression Tree with generic return type

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to take a MethodInfo and convert it into a callable Func. I have been successfully able to do this with a synchronous function of with method signature:

```
public AnyObject MyFuncName(AnotherObject message, IMessage messageMetadata)
```

Where `AnyObject` and `AnotherObject` is just any class. I have done so with the below code, after extracting the MethodInfo with reflection:

```
public static Func<Handler, object, IMessage, object> CompileHandler(Type handler, MethodInfo method, Type argumentType)
    {
        var instance = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Handler), "instance");
        var messageParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "message");
        var messageMetaParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IMessage), "messageMetadata");
        var methodCall = Expression.Call(
            Expression.Convert(instance, handler),
            method,
            Expression.Convert(messageParam, argumentType),
            Expression.Convert(messageMetaParam, typeof(IMessage)));

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<Handler, object, IMessage, object>>(
            methodCall,
            instance,
            messageParam,
            messageMetaParam).Compile();
    }
```

The above works. It will create the `Func` and I am able to call the function. I am now trying to make the function I am reflecting on asynchronous and will have the exact signature except it will be of return type `Task<AnyObject>` that gets converted to a `Func<Handler, object, IMessage, Task<object>>`

However, when I change all references above of `Func<Handler, object, IMessage, object>` to `Func<Handler, object, IMessage, Task<object>>`

When I do this, Expression.Lambda throws this exception:

```
Initialization method HandlerUnitTests.TestInitialize 
threw exception. System.ArgumentException: System.ArgumentException: Expression of type 
'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Handler.AnyObject]' cannot be used for return type 
'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Object]'
```

However it had no such objections when casting the return type to object when the Func signature was `Func<Handler, object, IMessage, object>`

Edit: The question here is how do I achieve the above?

Comment: Can you edit your question title summarise the _problem_ you're trying to solve here? See [ask] for more information.

Comment: You can't cast `Task<T>` to `Task<object>`, but you could write a helper async method that takes a `Task<T>` and returns a `Task<object>` and call it in your expression.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman do you have any sample code that may help me understand this a little better? Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the return value through your own method to cast the result;

```cs
private static async Task<object> Unwrap<T>(Task<T> task) => await task;
...
Expression.Call(
    new Func<Task<object>, Task<object>>(Unwrap).Method
        .GetGenericMethodDefinition()
        .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(...)),
    methodCall
)
```

But it does sound like you're solving the wrong problem. Your handler should probably be generic. Perhaps something like;

```cs
public abstract class Handler{
   public abstract Task<object> InvokeHandler(object message);
}

public abstract class Handler<M>:Handler{
    public abstract object HandleMessage(M message);
    public virtual Task<object> HandleMessageAsync(M message)
        => Task.FromResult(HandleMessage(message));
    public override Task<object> InvokeHandler(object message)
        => HandleMessageAsync((M)message);
}
```

Now your main loop can call any `Handler.InvokeHandler`, while all type conversions occur in the abstract generic base type. And without any runtime compilation.